# How can I rotate a label

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

In JavaFX 8 I would like to specify the css to rotate a Label so that instead of the text going from left to right, it goes from bottom to top.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any node can have it's rotation styled via CSS using the [`-fx-rotate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#node) css attribute.

> This is the angle of the rotation in degrees. Zero degrees is at 3 o'clock (directly to the right). Angle values are positive clockwise. Rotation is about the center.

So in your code or FXML you can have:

```
label.setStyle("vertical");
```

And in your css stylesheet you can define:

```
.vertical { -fx-rotate: -90; }
```

Also note James_D's answer suggestion of wrapping the label in a Group to account for the rotation when performing layout bounds calculations.

Answer (score 6):

Call `setRotate` on the label to rotate it about its center.

To allow layout panes to properly measure the bounds of the label after rotation, wrap it in a `Group`:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class RotatedLabelTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label label1 = new Label("Hello");
        Label label2 = new Label("World");

        label1.setRotate(-90);
        Group labelHolder = new Group(label1);

        HBox root = new HBox(5, labelHolder, label2);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 150);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know if there is a css for that?

Comment: No, I don't believe the rotate property is styleable.

Comment: Thanks for calling out the positioning. The Group thing does not seem to solve it

Comment: Create a new question and include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the positioning.

Comment: Ah, it is styleable. See jewelsea's answer, which I think is better than this one...

Answer (score 1):

You can easily set a label's rotation by specifying the degrees of rotation as per the code below:

`label.setRotate(45)`

for 45 degrees, for example.

if you want to set it after some operations, that is, after the label has been displayed in the User Interface, you can use

> Platform.runLater() lambda expression.
> i.e

```
Platform.runLater(()->
   label.setRotate(45);
  )
```

Comment: no screenshots of plain text please

Comment: Noted. I already made the necessary changes.

Comment: thanks :) now you might consider to fix the indentation of code snippet