# JavaFX Label Wrap Text Line Spacing

Tags: java, css, javafx, label, javafx-8

I need a feature so I can write down text vertically for my JavaFX 8 application. I came up with the idea of using a label, with a preferred width of 0, and wrap text on true. This indeed causes the text to be written vertically, as I require. But it consumes too much space, because the height between each line, so the line spacing is too much, but this already was at 0.

```
<Label fx:id="label_north" alignment="BOTTOM_CENTER" prefHeight="240.0" prefWidth="0.0" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true">
     <padding>
        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
     </padding>
</Label>
```

[Image Which Shows The Space Between Lines Is Massive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmqGy.png)

So does anyone know a css property to fix this? Because -fx-line-spacing's default is 0, so it is 0 right now, but well, 0 is massive?

Comment: Have you tried rotating the label: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25773053/32090 ?

Comment: I have tried that, but this also rotates the text itself. So the text is written down sideways, instead of, as displayed in the picture, horizontally but every letter below the other letter instead of next to each other

Comment: @BorisPavlović thank you for that comment, this is indeed possible apperently, and this indeed solves my issue, thank you so much! Sad I can't mark a comment as the correct answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about negative value for `-fx-line-spacing`? The default is 0, but it may accept negative values...